# TypeError: undefined is not a function when copying Map

Tags: javascript

Why is this code:

```
let a = {};
let m = new Map(a);
```

giving me the error:

```
code.0.0.128.js:33943 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new Map (native)
    at http://localhost:/code.0.0.128.js:33943:26
    at exports.default (http://localhost:/code.0.0.128.js:34006:7)
    at combination (http://localhost:/code.0.0.128.js:28672:30)
    at i (<anonymous>:1:14471)
    at u (<anonymous>:1:14757)
    at <anonymous>:1:17652
    at Object.dispatch (http://localhost:/code.0.0.128.js:28238:23)
    at dispatch (<anonymous>:1:18094)
    at http://localhost:/code.0.0.128.js:29398:17
```

If I try this I get no error:

```
let m = new Map();
```

Comment: a is not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

`a` needs to be an array with a key value structure in an array, or any other structure which maps to

```
[
    [key, value],
    [key, value],
]
```

From [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

> The **`Map`** object is a simple key/value map. Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> new Map([iterable])
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> - iterable
>
> Iterable is an Array or other iterable object whose elements are key-value pairs (2-element Arrays). Each key-value pair is added to the `new Map`. `null` is treated as undefined.

Comment: It can also be a Map object right? So I could define 'a' as follows: let a = new Map(); and then my code above will work.

Comment: Even though it is still marked as experimental a reference to [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) might be of use. Because this function would allow the necessary conversion in a standard way in future.